# Stack overflow при маппинге JPA-DTO при отношении one/many to one/many

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Суть в том, что есть неких 2 класса А и Б. Поскольку есть отношение, то соответственно класс А ссылается на Б и наоборот. Для обоих классов есть DTO и JPA реализация. Есть соответственно маппер для всего этого дела (в моём случае в конструкторе, но не столь важно). И получается следующая ситуация с маппингом: вызываем маппер А_DTO в А_JPA, в следствии чего для поля Б_DTO вызывается Б_DTO в Б_JPA, у которого в свою очередь есть поле А_DTO и так далее, в следствии чего выпадает stack overflow и все падает. Как избавиться от подобной зависимости?
Пример кода (аннотации и лишние поля убрал, ломбок стоит):

```
public abstract class Template implements Serializable {

    protected Template(Template templateFrom) {
        setTemplateGroup(templateFrom.getTemplateGroup());
    }

    public abstract TemplateGroup getTemplateGroup();

    public abstract void setTemplateGroup(TemplateGroup template);

}

public class TemplateDTO extends Template {

    private TemplateGroup templateGroup;

    public TemplateDTO(Template templateFrom) {
        super(templateFrom);
    }

    public TemplateGroup getTemplateGroup() {
        return templateGroup;
    }
}

public class TemplateJPA extends Template {

    private TemplateGroupJPA templateGroup;

    public TemplateJPA(Template templateFrom) {
        super(templateFrom);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTemplateGroup(TemplateGroup templateGroup) {
        if (templateGroup == null) {
            this.templateGroup = null;
            return;
        }
        this.templateGroup = new TemplateGroupJPA(templateGroup);
    }

}

////////////////////////////////////////

public abstract class TemplateGroup implements Serializable {

    protected TemplateGroup(TemplateGroup from) {
        setTemplates(from.getTemplates());
    }

    public abstract Set<Template> getTemplates();

    public abstract void setTemplates(Set<Template> templates);

}

public class TemplateGroupDTO extends TemplateGroup {

    private Set<TemplateDTO> templates;

    public TemplateGroupDTO(TemplateGroup from) {
        super(from);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Template> getTemplates() {
        return (templates == null) ? null : new HashSet<>(templates);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTemplates(Set<Template> templates) {
        this.templates = (templates == null) ? null
                : templates.stream().map(TemplateDTO::new).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
}

public class TemplateGroupJPA extends TemplateGroup {

    private Set<TemplateJPA> templates;

    public TemplateGroupJPA(TemplateGroup from) {
        super(from);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Template> getTemplates() {
        return (templates == null) ? null : new HashSet<>(templates);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTemplates(Set<Template> templates) {
        this.templates = templates.stream().map(TemplateJPA::new).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
}
```

Comment: Это происходит при toString?

Comment: У меня данная ошибка происходит при выводе данных внутри объекта. Тэгните меня, если у Вас именно в этои проблема

Comment: @Antonio112009 нет проблема в `aJPA = toJPA(aDTO)`, который зацикливается.

Comment: можете привести примеры кода?

Comment: @Antonio112009 добавил